Filtering queryset depending on incoming parameters?
I have the filter parameters that I get through GET request. These parameters are used for filtering QuerySet:
class FilterData(TypedDict):
    title: str
    min_price: int
    max_price: int
    freeDelivery: bool
    available: bool
    tags: list[int | None]

As you can see, the list of tags can be empty and this field shouldn't be in the filter query.
So what's the best way to change my filter query depending on incoming parameters?
if might help, but I'm not sure it's a good solution:
if not tags:
            result = Product.objects.filter(
                Q(
                    price__gte=filter_data["min_price"],
                    price__lte=filter_data["max_price"],
                )
                & Q(freeDelivery=filter_data["freeDelivery"])
                & Q(available=filter_data["available"])
                & Q(title__icontains=filter_data["title"]))
            ).order_by(order_field)
        else:
            result = Product.objects.filter(
                Q(
                    price__gte=filter_data["min_price"],
                    price__lte=filter_data["max_price"],
                )
                & Q(freeDelivery=filter_data["freeDelivery"])
                & Q(available=filter_data["available"])
                & Q(title__icontains=filter_data["title"])
                & Q(tags__contains=[1, 2, 3])
            ).order_by(order_field)

Thx.

I'd suggest to use https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/main/.

[Edit] your code. There is an issue with indentation.

To not repeat yourself, you can do this:
filters = Q( ... ) # all the filters except tags
if tags:
   filters &= Q(tags__contains=[1, 2, 3])
result = Product.objects.filter(filters).order_by(order_field)

Alternatively, you could just use filter methods:
result = Product.objects.filter(price__gte=filter_data["min_price"], ...).order_by(order_field)
if tags:
   result = result.filter(tags__contains=[1, 2, 3])


OP doesn’t want to use keyword arguments for a reason that is probably why Q instances are used. Nonetheless, +1 for a good answer.
